# BeautifulSoup scraping Div class element second argument

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BS for the web scrapping. I can easily find the defined class, see the screen below, but it will show me the all ements, with all sizes.

Is there a way, how to filter the second argument in the DIV, which is the size? Or do I have to simply scrap all of it and then filter it? I'd like to have just this element/DIV for the size S.

[image: DIV Class screen]

Comment: Please show us your current code to understand what you already tried and explain a little bit more what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend your selection of elements, based on low details from your question, I just wanna point out [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
soup.select('div.productConfiguration__selectVariant[data-product-size="S"]')
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<div data-product-size="S" class="productConfiguration__selectVariant some classes">content</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select('div.productConfiguration__selectVariant[data-product-size="S"]')
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for my badly posted question. Have a nice evening.